Jest, React, TS ReferenceError: document is not defined
 /**
 * @jest-environment jsdom
 */
import React from "react";
import { render, screen, fireEvent, cleanup } from "@testing-library/react";
import Zustand from "../component/Zustand";
import '@testing-library/jest-dom'

afterEach(() => {
  cleanup(); // Resets the DOM after each test suite
})

describe("Компонент Zustand", () => {
  it("отрисовывает начальное значение счетчика", () => {
    render(<Zustand />);
    expect(screen.getByText(/Count: 0/i)).toBeInTheDocument();
    expect(screen.getByText(/Increase/i)).toBeInTheDocument();
    expect(screen.getByText(/Decrease/i)).toBeInTheDocument();
  });

  it("вызывает increaseCount при клике на кнопку Increase", () => {
    const mockStore = require("../zustand/store").default; // Получаем мокаемый store

    render(<Zustand />); // Рендерим компонент Zustand
    const increaseButton = screen.getByText(/Increase/i); // Находим кнопку Increase
    const resetButton = screen.getByText(/Reset/i); // Находим кнопку Reset

    fireEvent.click(increaseButton); // Симулируем клик по кнопке
    fireEvent.click(increaseButton); // Симулируем еще один клик по кнопке

    expect(mockStore().increaseCount).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(2); // Проверяем, что функция increaseCount была вызвана дважды
    expect(mockStore().resetCount).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(0); // Проверяем, что функция resetCount не была вызвана

    fireEvent.click(resetButton); // Симулируем клик по кнопке Reset
    expect(mockStore().resetCount).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1); // Проверяем, что функция resetCount была вызвана один раз
    expect(mockStore().increaseCount).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(2); // Проверяем, что функция increaseCount была вызвана дважды
  });
});

module.exports = {
  // Указываем, что тестовая среда - jsdom
  testEnvironment: 'jsdom',

  // Преобразование файлов с расширением .ts и .tsx с использованием ts-jest
  transform: {
    '^.+\\.(ts|tsx)$': 'ts-jest',
    '^.+\\.css$': 'jest-css-modules-transform', // Для работы с CSS модулями
  },

  // Подключение расширений файлов, которые Jest будет обрабатывать
  moduleFileExtensions: ['ts', 'tsx', 'js', 'jsx'],

  // Игнорирование трансформации для некоторых модулей, чтобы ускорить тесты
  transformIgnorePatterns: ['/node_modules/(?!@testing-library)'],

  // Дополнительные опции для покрытия, если нужно
  collectCoverage: true,
  coverageReporters: ['json', 'lcov', 'text', 'clover'],

  // Для правильного использования библиотек для работы с DOM
  setupFilesAfterEnv: ['<rootDir>/src/setupTests.ts'],

  // Директивы, чтобы Jest игнорировал случайные предупреждения и улучшал производительность
  silent: false,
  verbose: true,
};


FAIL  src/tests/ZustandIncDec.test.tsx
Компонент Zustand
× отрисовывает начальное значение счетчика (34 ms)
× вызывает increaseCount при клике на кнопку Increase (7 ms)
● Компонент Zustand › отрисовывает начальное значение счетчика
The error below may be caused by using the wrong test environment, see https://jestjs.io/docs/configuration#testenvironment-string.
Consider using the "jsdom" test environment.

ReferenceError: document is not defined

  14 |   it("отрисовывает начальное значение счетчика", () => {
  15 |     render(<Zustand />);
> 16 |     expect(screen.getByText(/Count: 0/i)).toBeInTheDocument();
     |                   ^
  17 |     expect(screen.getByText(/Increase/i)).toBeInTheDocument();
  18 |     expect(screen.getByText(/Decrease/i)).toBeInTheDocument();
  19 |   });

  at node_modules/nwsapi/src/nwsapi.js:215:21
  at Factory (node_modules/nwsapi/src/nwsapi.js:245:6)
  at initNwsapi (node_modules/jsdom/lib/jsdom/living/helpers/selectors.js:10:10)
  at exports.addNwsapi (node_modules/jsdom/lib/jsdom/living/helpers/selectors.js:38:24)
  at HTMLBodyElementImpl.ElementImpl.matches (node_modules/jsdom/lib/jsdom/living/nodes/Element-impl.js:569:19)
  at HTMLBodyElement.matches (node_modules/jsdom/lib/jsdom/living/generated/Element.js:655:34)
  at queryAllByText (node_modules/@testing-library/dom/dist/queries/text.js:26:60)
  at node_modules/@testing-library/dom/dist/query-helpers.js:74:17
  at node_modules/@testing-library/dom/dist/query-helpers.js:52:17
  at node_modules/@testing-library/dom/dist/query-helpers.js:95:19
  at Object.<anonymous> (src/__tests__/ZustandIncDec.test.tsx:16:19)

● Компонент Zustand › вызывает increaseCount при клике на кнопку Increase
The error below may be caused by using the wrong test environment, see https://jestjs.io/docs/configuration#testenvironment-string.
Consider using the "jsdom" test environment.

ReferenceError: document is not defined

  23 |
  24 |     render(<Zustand />); // Рендерим компонент Zustand
> 25 |     const increaseButton = screen.getByText(/Increase/i); // Находим кнопку Increase
     |                                   ^
  26 |     const resetButton = screen.getByText(/Reset/i); // Находим кнопку Reset
  27 |
  28 |     fireEvent.click(increaseButton); // Симулируем клик по кнопке

  at node_modules/nwsapi/src/nwsapi.js:215:21
  at Factory (node_modules/nwsapi/src/nwsapi.js:245:6)
  at initNwsapi (node_modules/jsdom/lib/jsdom/living/helpers/selectors.js:10:10)
  at exports.addNwsapi (node_modules/jsdom/lib/jsdom/living/helpers/selectors.js:38:24)
  at HTMLBodyElementImpl.ElementImpl.matches (node_modules/jsdom/lib/jsdom/living/nodes/Element-impl.js:569:19)
  28 |     fireEvent.click(increaseButton); // Симулируем клик по кнопке

  at node_modules/nwsapi/src/nwsapi.js:215:21
  at Factory (node_modules/nwsapi/src/nwsapi.js:245:6)
  at initNwsapi (node_modules/jsdom/lib/jsdom/living/helpers/selectors.js:10:10)
  at exports.addNwsapi (node_modules/jsdom/lib/jsdom/living/helpers/selectors.js:38:24)
  at HTMLBodyElementImpl.ElementImpl.matches (node_modules/jsdom/lib/jsdom/living/nodes/Element-impl.js:569:19)
  at HTMLBodyElement.matches (node_modules/jsdom/lib/jsdom/living/generated/Element.js:655:34)
  at queryAllByText (node_modules/@testing-library/dom/dist/queries/text.js:26:60)
  at node_modules/@testing-library/dom/dist/query-helpers.js:74:17
  at node_modules/@testing-library/dom/dist/query-helpers.js:52:17
  at node_modules/@testing-library/dom/dist/query-helpers.js:95:19
  at Object.<anonymous> (src/__tests__/ZustandIncDec.test.tsx:25:35)

уже все перепробовал игрался с jsdom уже делал разные виды конфигураций ts конфигурацию json в package.json пихал конфигурацию 35 раз уже переустанавливал jest и другие зависимости ничего не помогает не знаю что не так

пожалуйста, не добавляйте код/данные/текст ошибок картинками.

I've got the same issue, when I use a previous package-lock it works fine + npm ci, but doing a fresh install I get the same error. From package-lock nothing jest related seems to have changed.
Jest config is set to jsdom, tried adding the rule to the test file same thing.

добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! переведите, пожалуйста, текст ответа (нажав [edit] ниже текста ответа) на русский язык

Perhaps the problem lies in the new version of one of the dependencies that are used by jest, I rolled back all the dependencies that are used in jest and also jest itself deleted the coverage, node_modules, package-lock.json and npm i folder 1 version back and the problem disappeared Test Suites: 1 passed, 1 total
Tests: 2 passed, 2 total

возможно, проблема кроется в новой версий какой-то из зависимостей, которые используются jest.
я откатил все зависимости, которые используются в jest, и так же сам jest на одну версию назад, удалил папку coverage, node_modules, package-lock.json и выполнил npm i, и проблема изчезла.


переведите, пожалуйста, текст ответа (нажав [edit] ниже текста ответа) на русский язык

Here ya go, broken release. solutions here https://github.com/dperini/nwsapi/issues/135

добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! переведите, пожалуйста, текст ответа (нажав [edit] ниже текста ответа) на русский язык
